# How to display another text box after user inserted value in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My task is to make the user to insert their age in a text box. If their age more than 18 years old, it will appear another text box.

Is there any possible JavaScript or jQuery coding to do that?

```html
<label>Age: <span class="required">* </span></label>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="">
<div style="display: none" id="age1">
  <label control-label ">Another textbox: </label>
       <input type="text "   name=" " value=" " name=" " > 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
$('#age').change( function() {
  if ($(this).val() > 18) {
    $('#age1').css('display','block');
  } else {
    $('#age1').css('display','none');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `onchange` function to age:

```html
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" onchange="addInput(this.value)" placeholder="">

<script>
  function addInput(age) {
    var value = parseInt(age);
    if (value > 18) {
      document.getElementById("age1").style = "display:block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("age1").style = "display:none"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of HTML markup errors which I have corrected on the snippet below.

Use `focusout` and check if given age is a number or not using RegEx like below:

```js
$("#age").focusout(function() {
  let age = $(this).val();
  if (/^[0-9]+?$/.test(age) && age >= 18) // check RegEx match only number (age)
    $("#age1").show();
  else
    $("#age1").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Age: <span class="required">* </span></label>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="" />

<div style="display: none" id="age1">
  <label control-label>Another textbox: </label>
  <input type="text " name=" " value=" " name=" " />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this code. I have added code so that if you change value to less than 18. It again sets the property to display:none.

```
 $('#age').keyup(function(){
 if ($('#age').val() >= 18)
 {
 ('#age1').css('display','block');
 }
 else
 {
 $('#age1').css('display','none');
 }
});
```

Also, You have some error in this code:-

```
<label control-label>Another textbox: </label>
```

I think you should add class attribute before control-label.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following jQuery event with your HTML and it will work:

```js
$("#age").keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() > 18){
    $("#age1").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label >Age: <span class="required">* </span></label>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="">
<div style="display: none;" id="age1">
   <label  control-label">Another textbox: </label>
   <input type="text"   name="" value="" name="" >  
</div>
```

You can also do this without jQuery, (using only JS, it is faster, as it doesnt need any library to load first). Here I have added `onkeyup` attribute in the input field `#age`, and `myFunction()` works the same.

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("age").value > 18) {
    document.getElementById("age1").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Age: <span class="required">* </span></label>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="" onkeyup="myFunction();">
<div style="display: none;" id="age1">
  <label control-label ">Another textbox: </label>
   <input type="text "   name=" " value=" " name=" " >  
</div>
```